# Youtube only buffering in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: video, 18.04, youtube

I recently upgraded from 16.04 to 18.04 and everything works fine except I cannot watch YouTube anymore. It doesn't matter if its in Firefox or chrome, all I get is a black screen and the buffering symbol rotating endlessly.
Netflix and other streaming services seem fine though.

No error messages, no info. Here's some debug info from YouTube:

```
{
  "ns": "yt",
  "el": "detailpage",
  "cpn": "ukqJ1Pkc3hFNrRjM",
  "docid": "UUrddqT9i_s",
  "ver": 2,
  "referrer": "https://www.youtube.com/",
  "cmt": "0",
  "plid": "AAVsjksRhoKfiDto",
  "ei": "4xkAW9jTOMXX7gT23KLIBw",
  "fmt": "244",
  "fs": "0",
  "rt": "6.962",
  "of": "88EcndvSiiJtXH_gbFT7aQ",
  "euri": "",
  "lact": 1,
  "cl": "197048268",
  "mos": 0,
  "state": "49",
  "vm": "CAEQARgE",
  "volume": 100,
  "subscribed": "1",
  "c": "WEB",
  "cver": "2.20180517",
  "cplayer": "UNIPLAYER",
  "cbr": "Firefox",
  "cbrver": "60.0",
  "cos": "X11",
  "hl": "en_US",
  "cr": "SE",
  "len": "430",
  "fexp": "23702717,23708904,23708906,23708910,23710476,23712544,23718325,23720702,23721699,23721898,23723303,23723618,23723927,23724834,23726563,23727194,23729169,23729689,23730469,23730604,23731733,23732854,23733751,23736483,23737658,23737969,23738492,23738897,23739454,23739764,23740493,23740991,23741036,23741665,23741719,23741852,23742144,23742665,9422596,9449243,9466850,9470250,9471235,9476619,9485000",
  "feature": "g-high-rec",
  "afmt": "251",
  "at": "2_3",
  "cc": ".en.nP7-2PuUl7o",
  "vct": "0.000",
  "vd": "430.000",
  "vpl": "",
  "vbu": "",
  "vpa": "0",
  "vsk": "0",
  "ven": "0",
  "vpr": "1",
  "vrs": "0",
  "vns": "2",
  "vec": "null",
  "vvol": "1",
  "creationTime": 495925,
  "totalVideoFrames": 0,
  "droppedVideoFrames": 0,
  "corruptedVideoFrames": 0,
  "lct": "0.000",
  "lsk": true,
  "lmf": false,
  "lbw": "24420486.667",
  "lhd": "0.010",
  "lst": "0.000",
  "laa": "",
  "lva": "",
  "lar": "",
  "lvr": "",
  "lvh": "r3---sn-uxaxovg-5gok",
  "lab": "",
  "lvb": "",
  "ismb": 10950000,
  "relative_loudness": "-6.749",
  "optimal_format": "480p",
  "user_qual": "auto",
  "debug_videoId": "UUrddqT9i_s",
  "0sz": false,
  "op": "1",
  "yof": false,
  "dis": "",
  "gpu": "GeForce_GTX_1050/PCIe/SSE2",
  "cgr": true,
  "debug_playbackQuality": "large",
  "debug_date": "Sat May 19 2018 14:34:51 GMT+0200 (CEST)"
}
```

Comment: Are you able to ping youtube.com ? Type this at terminal `ping www.youtube.com`

Comment: @C0deDaedalus Yeah, Youtube.com works just fine and i can ping it. It only the video itself that's the problem

Comment: >"all I get is a black screen and the buffering symbol rotating endlessly"// Does the rest of the page load? Do you get the controls loading? Can you use the cog menu to change to the lowest quality, does it start - does your computer indicate (eg via `sudo iptraf`) that it's actually downloading content? Do you have any extensions - like uBlock, or other ad blockers?

Comment: Do you get all 6 boxes checked here? https://www.youtube.com/html5

Answer (score 0):

Does your computer have speaker/headphone connected? If not try connecting headphone or speaker and try. I had the exact same issue, when speaker/headphone is not connected, so it could be an issue related to audio not being available.

Note: My ubuntu is running in virtualbox VM.

Answer (score -1):

I also faced this problem when I upgrade from Ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04, My issue has resolved after I made a small change.

I turned off a Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) extension, Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) is an algorithm that can identify and block dubious cross-origin resource loads in web browsers before they reach the web page. CORB reduces the risk of leaking sensitive data by keeping it further from cross-origin web pages.

In most browsers, it keeps such data out of untrusted script execution contexts. In browsers with [Site Isolation](https://security.googleblog.com/2018/07/mitigating-spectre-with-site-isolation.html), it can keep such data out of untrusted renderer processes entirely, helping even against side-channel attacks like Spectre. This is for both Chrome as well as Firefox. And then everything looks fine.

Comment: My Youtube was not streaming on Chrome because of the CORB extension which I added in Chrome, an extension which is used for taking data from the different domain. So I disabled it, and now everything is working fine.

Comment: Alright, I retracted my *not-an-answer* flag. Could you please [edit] your post when you want to clarify something or add information? It’s best to have everything relevant in one place. Additionally, comments may be deleted for various reasons. Thanks.